# How is better to relate this tables?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have this tables:

- TableA(IDA, ...)
- TableB(IDB, ...)
- TableAB(IDA, IDB)
- TableD(IDD, IDA, IDB)

I need that the TableD has a reation with TableA and TableB, so I can do two things, create a single relation with the tableAB, but I have the option to create a relation with TableA and other relation with TableB.

Which is the best option, to relate with the main tables (TableA and TableB) or relate with the middle table TalbaBA?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me tableAB and tableD do the same thing

Comment: Your table AB have the combination of A &B. In that case, you don't actually need either (A & B) or (AB). At the same time, table D seems to be replica of TableAB

Comment: It seems that TableAB is a relation table between TableA ans TableB.

If so, why do you want to make another relation between TableA and TableB adding an IDD?

We need some more information on the real contents of the tables and the relations you want obtain.

Comment: so, table d should either relate to table a, table b, or table ab? meaning that ida and idb are nullable in table d?